# R - How to find pair combination of variables inside a group

Tags: r

I need to create a network in which the relationship among actors is represented by a group variable. I mean in my example, a and b have a tie because they belong to group 1. I need to represent these ties in a network matrix form as the expected output represent. The output should contain the combination of pairs that are in the same group.

Input:

| Entity | Group |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 1 |
| c | 2 |
| d | 2 |
| e | 2 |

Expected output:

| Entity1 | Entity2 | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 1 |
| c | d | 2 |
| c | e | 2 |
| d | e | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

We can use `combn` grouped by 'Group'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Group) %>% 
   summarise(out = list(combn(Entity, 2, simplify = FALSE)),
       .groups = 'drop') %>% 
   unnest(c(out)) %>% 
   unnest_wider(c(out))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Entity = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), Group = c(1, 
1, 2, 2, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```